# How can i take value from column? (Java)

Tags: java, jtable

I do simple alarm and i need show alert if value from column 0 == today.

```
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);        

      try {

        File currDir= new File ("Baza.db");
        String sc = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
         sc = sc.substring(0, sc.length());

         String url = "jdbc:sqlite://"+sc;
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
         Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Day FROM Month");

         jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
         if(jTable1.getValueAt(0, 0).equals(day)){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Do your question!");
      }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

I trying use method getColumn, getColumnModel and getSelectedColumn but but nothing compared my calculations..

Comment: You should use debugger or logger to check what actually `jTable1.getValueAt(0, 0)` on runtime is.

Comment: `jTable1.getValueAt(0, 0) `  give me "6" (value from column 0 and row 0) but equals dont worth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `day` variable is of type `int` and `jTable1.getValueAt(0, 0)` returns an `Object` hence both are of different type and will always return `false` upon comparison.

As you want to compare the equality of them as string, hence you should change your comparison from this,

```
if(jTable1.getValueAt(0, 0).equals(day)){
```

to,

```
if(String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(0, 0)).equals(String.valueOf(day))){
```

Or, you may parse the value in Jtable column to `int` and then compare the integer value like this,

```
if(Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(0, 0).toString()) == day){
```

However, I'll prefer the first way to compare as string, as second way can run into `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Ohh, nice, very thanks :)
Hmm, how can I compare values ​​from the first column not just from one row?

Comment: @DawidRuciński: `getValueAt(0, 0)` will refer to the very first row's very first column. Similarly, `getValueAt(0, 1)` will refer to first row and second column. So if you want to access any of them, you can have nested for loops and access any value. Can you tell me what further you exactly want to do?

Comment: Here is a sample code for nested for loops and how you can access each value from JTable, `for (int i = 0;i<jTable.getRowCount();i++) {
 for (int j=0;j<jTable.getColumnCount();j++) {
  System.out.println(jTable.getValueAt(i, j));
 }
}`

Comment: Thanks i use for loops. I still want to run music alarm if this requirement is true. But I have not tried to do it yet.

Comment: @You can debug and try yourself and ensure it works fine.